# While publishing report with embedded password getting error in Tableau with google spreadsheet as data source

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have data in google drive in spreadsheet. I have proper read/write access to that spreadsheet. I can able to connect the same as my data source to the Tableau and built my reports and dashboard. However, while publishing with embed the password I'm getting error.
[image]

Please help me how I can publish the report to Tableau server with embed password. I have connected the Google spreadsheet with Tableau Google Drive connection. Where it get connected successfully.

Comment: Have you tried what the error message told you to do?

Comment: @MUFF. Yes I got the resolution please follow my steps mentioned below in Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my datasource is from Google Drive. I have to have the access of GCP(Google Cloud Portal) https://console.cloud.google.com/
Create your API under APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen and get the Client ID and Client secret.

On the Tableau Server computer, open the shell and run the following commands to specify the access token and URI:

tsm configuration set -k oauth.google.client_id -v <your_client_ID>

tsm configuration set -k oauth.google.client_secret -v <your_client_secret>

tsm configuration set -k oauth.google.redirect_uri -v <your_authorized_redirect_URI>

tsm pending-changes apply

All supported connectors are listed under Saved Credentials for Data Sources on users’ My Account Settings page on Tableau Server. Users manage their saved credentials for each connector.

Reference:
https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/config_oauth_google.htm
https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/protected_auth.htm